# How to connect Cassandra to localhost using cqlsh?

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

I set rpc_port to the public IP address, and now I can connect to Cassandra just fine from an outside server.

However, I cannot connect from the Cassandra server itself, using cqlsh

I am getting an error.Thar are:

```
 Connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160
```

Is there a configuration, I can change to be able to connect from the server itself ?

Answer (score 21):

1. Check the `cassandra.yaml` file on the line with `rpc_port :` normally by default `= 9160`
2. Login to the machine hosting `cassandra`
3. Try `cqlsh 127.0.0.1 9160` : should be ok in any case
4. try `cqlsh [IP of host] 9160` : if ok then `cassandra` reachable from lan, if ok then `cassandra` is not reachable from `lan` but only `localhost 127.0.0.1`

Comment: Thank you for pointing the direction, actually in my case I found `start_rpc: false`, setting it to true fixed the problem.

Answer (score 9):

You need to connect to cassandra through the `rpc_address` defined in `cassandra.yaml`. For example, I use `cqlsh 10.0.80.49 9160`.

Comment: Daniel - I am trying to run `cassandra` on google cloud and want to use external IP. I specified the external address in `rpc_address` but got error when trying to start `cassandra`- `INFO  [main] 2019-12-17 19:00:37,251 Server.java:159 - Starting listening for CQL clients on /xx.xx.xxx.xx:9042 (unencrypted)...
Exception (java.lang.IllegalStateException) encountered during startup: Failed to bind port 9042 on xx.xx.x.xx.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to bind port 9042 on x.x.x.x.x.`. Would you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry no, I don't know what the issue is from your description. Perhaps try the Cassandra users mailing list or other community support forums?

Answer (score 9):

Consider changing `/etc/cassandra.yaml`:

```
# Whether to start the thrift rpc server.
start_rpc: false
```

to

```
start_rpc: true
```

Comment: Actually, I have such an option and such a problem

Answer (score 8):

if you see this in cassandra logs:

```
INFO  [main] 2015-07-21 12:06:27,426 CassandraDaemon.java:406 - Not starting RPC server as requested. Use JMX (StorageService->startRPCServer()) or nodetool (enablethrift) to start it
```

then just open a terminal and

```
$ nodetool enablethrift
```

as written in the INFO message. Should now work. Got this when my system upgraded to cassandra 2.2.0

Answer (score 5):

If you are on OSX

```
brew install cassandra
```

First start the Cassandra

```
cassandra
```

[image: Start the Cassandra]
Connect via CQL shell

```
cqlsh 127.0.0.1
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Maybe start cassandra on your local machine by `bin/cassandra -f` first?

Answer (score 3):

It's not listening on `127.0.0.1` since you told it to only listen on `<public IP>`. Make the listen address `0.0.0.0` to listen on all addresses (or just omit it if possible as this is usually the default). See [Listening Sockets .NET tutorial](http://www.winsocketdotnetworkprogramming.com/serverlisteningnetworksocketdotnet9.html) or any other socket tutorial to get a basic understanding of socket binding.

Update (@[c45556037](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976445/how-to-connect-cassandra-to-localhost-using-cqlsh/24960024?noredirect=1#comment45556037_24960024)):

Note that `listen_address` is the one for *other nodes* to use to connect to this one (a misleading name). `rpc_address` is the actual address to locally bind to. It's unclear from the [2.0 docs](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html?scroll=reference_ds_qfg_n1r_1k__listen_address) and is explained better in the [1.0 docs](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/configuration/node_configuration#listen-address).

Comment: But cassandra from datastax, says not to set 0.0.0.0 to listen addres in the .yaml file itself? Why so

Comment: Cassandra throws an error when I do this. It is not recommended

Comment: @JonathanKelsey without more details, your comment isn't very helpful

Comment: Ok, this causes an error in Cassandra 2.1.5.469. A typical yaml will have this comment about the listen address: 'Setting this to 0.0.0.0 is always wrong.'  Or from the Cassandra apache FAQ we have this note 'Cassandra is a gossip-based distributed system. ListenAddress is also "contact me here address," i.e., the address it tells other nodes to reach it at. Telling other nodes "contact me on any of my addresses" is a bad idea; if different nodes in the cluster pick different addresses for you, Bad Things happen.' In short this is simply bad advice

Comment: @JonathanKelsey Sigh. See the 2nd part, it clearly tells one to set `rpc_address` rather that `listen_address`.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same situation while starting cqlsh . I got following error while starting cassandra

Enter only ----cassandra----- in terminal.

it will show all jars and log files . if terminal hang , just escape from it and then enter cqlsh. then it will enter to cassandra cli.

This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Exception connecting to localhost/9160. reason: connection refused

Connection refused to cassandra cli mode .

goto the root directory of cassandra :

```
bin/cassandra -- host {host-ip} --port {9160}
```

if you are having trouble with this , check your {cassandra-root-directory}/conf/cassandra.yaml

the thrift ip or rpc_address is the address used as the host-ip for connecting to cli .
make it your local IP and if you are having trouble connecting using the port 9160 , try changing the rpc_port to 8070 and now try connecting to cassandra-cli mode using the command

```
bin/cassandra --host {local-IP} --port 8070
```

This worked for me, hope it works for you too .

Answer (score 0):

for `2.0.5` the following works for me ..

```
   $CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cqlsh xx.xx.xxx.xxx 9160
```

Comment: Could you explain why this answer is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please execute the below query to resolve the issue

```
#!/bin/bash
export CASSANDRA_HOME=/opt/apache-cassandra-2.1.8
export CQLSH_HOST=192.168.1.200
export CQLSH_PORT=9042
echo $@
$CASSANDRA_HOME/bin/cqlsh $@'
```

> Make sure to change the IP and location of cassandra Home Directory

Answer (score 0):

Use this command

```
sudo service cassandra start
```

to start cassandra and then use

```
cqlsh command
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing /etc/cassandra-env.sh:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=true"
not "true" but "false"
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false"
```

sudo service cassandra restart

Answer (score 0):

How to change default port 9042 in Cassandra ?

I resolved issue using below steps :

1)  Stop cassandara services

```
sudo su -
systemctl stop datastax-agent
systemctl stop opscenterd
systemctl stop app-dse
```

2)  Take backup and Change port from 9042 to 9035

```
cp /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/bkp_cassandra.yaml
vi /opt/dse/resources/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml

native_transport_port: 9035
```

3)  Start Cassandra services

```
systemctl start datastax-agent
systemctl start opscenterd
systemctl start app-dse
```

4) create cqlshrc file.

```
vi  /root/.cassandra/cqlshrc

[connection]
hostname = 198.168.1.100
port = 9035
```