# cqlsh connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160

Tags: connection, localhost, cqlsh

I am totally new to Cassandra and met the following error when using cqlsh:

```
cqlsh

Connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160
```

I read the solutions from the following link and tried them all. But none of them works for me.

[How to connect Cassandra to localhost using cqlsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23976445/how-to-connect-cassandra-to-localhost-using-cqlsh)

I am working on CentOS6.5 and installed Cassandra2.0 using yum intall dsc20.

Answer (score 4):

I ran into the same issue running the same OS and same install method.  While the cassandra service claims that it's starting ok, if you run `service cassandra status` it would tell me that the process was dead.  Here are the steps I took to fix it:

Viewing the log file at `/var/log/cassandra/cassandra.log` gave told me that my heap size was too small.  Manually set the heap size in `/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh`:

```
MAX_HEAP_SIZE="1G"
HEAP_NEWSIZE="256M"
```

Tips on setting the heap size for your system can be found [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_tune_jvm_c.html)

Next, the error log claimed the stack size was too small.  Once again in `/etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra-env.sh` find a line that looks like `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss128k"` and raise that number to `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Xss256k"`

Lastly, the log complained that the local url was misformed and threw a java exception.  I found the answer to the last part [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7496640/problem-on-starting-cassandra). Basically, you want to manually bind your server's hostname in your `/etc/hosts` file.

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain server1.example.com
```

Hope this helps~

Answer (score 1):

Change:

## /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml

## Whether to start the thrift rpc server.

start_rpc: false

## to

start_rpc: true